# increment float number with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i want button (+) to increment 0.3  and (-) discrement by 0.3 with range

```js
function move1(){
 var x1l = document.getElementById("imjv1l").value;

    document.getElementById('val_img1_l').value=x1l; 
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.1" style="width:100%;" oninput="move1(this.value)" id="imjv1l">
<output id="val_img1_l">50</output><br>
<input type="button" value="+"><input type="button" value="-">
```

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: yes i tried with (-)  `function img1_min_w(){
   document.getElementById("imjv1l").value-0.1;
   move1();`
}
            and with (+)     `function img1_plu_w(){
   document.getElementById("imjv1l").value+0.1;
   move1();
}`  but dont work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
    function increment(plusMinus) {
        var x1l = parseFloat(document.getElementById("imjv1l").value);
        x1l += plusMinus * 0.3;
        x1l = x1l.toFixed(2)
        document.getElementById("imjv1l").value=x1l;
        document.getElementById("val_img1_l").value=x1l;

    }

    function move1(){
     var x1l = document.getElementById("imjv1l").value;

        document.getElementById('val_img1_l').value=x1l; 
    }
```

```html
 
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.1" style="width:100%;" oninput="move1(this.value)" id="imjv1l">
    <output id="val_img1_l">50</output><br>
    <input type="button" value="+" onclick="increment(1)"><input type="button" value="-" onclick="increment(-1)">
```

5

Comment: he adding ex: 50.30 ,50.60 ,90 , etc ... but i want add like 50.3 ,50.6 ,50.9 etc ,,, you can solve the problem?

Comment: change `toFixed(2)` to `toFixed(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
function move1(){
 var x1l = Number(document.getElementById("imjv1l").value);
    x1l += 0.3;
    document.getElementById('val_img1_l').value=x1l; 
}

function applyDelta(shouldIncrease){
   var delta = (shouldIncrease) ? 0.3 : -0.3;
   document.getElementById("imjv1l").value = Number(document.getElementById("imjv1l").value) + delta;
  move1();
}
```

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" step="0.3" style="width:100%;" oninput="move1(this.value)" id="imjv1l">
<output id="val_img1_l">50</output><br>
<input type="button" value="+" onclick="applyDelta(true)"><input type="button" value="-" onclick="applyDelta(false)">
```

Comment: you can solve problem :when i move range to Beginning the value become 0.3 i want 0 , and solve problem with 0.8999999999 i want only 0.8 , 0. 6